# Test the Speed of a Local Area Network

Tags: networking, lan

How can I test the speed of a LAN?  I hope there is something baked into Windows to do this, because I am unable to install any third-party products.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well you can just look at the network in the control panel and see if the LAN is connected at 10/100/1000 mbit. But that doesn't tell you the whole story. If you want to test the speed between two PCs, you really need a tool to do it. One tool I've used that seems pretty good is '[iperf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf/)', it's just a commandline EXE, doesn't require any install. 'ping' will tell you the latency, but not the available bandwidth.

Example usage of iperf:

On one PC run it in 'server' mode:
`iperf -s`

On another PC run it in 'client' mode, and give it the IP of the first PC: `iperf -c 12.34.56.67`

You may need to use larger packet sizes to get the full speed, try adding `-l 64K -w 64K` or something.

Comment: +1 for iperf. Another option would be to use the built-in ftp client, which displays the transfer rate, but iperf is a better option, because with FTP and gigabit LAN the hard drives are likely a bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [psping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psping) from Sysinternals which can be used on a similar way to iperf. You need to run the executable on server mode in one machine and the same executable on client mode on a second machine.

### On first machine:

psping -s own_ip:any_unused_port

Example: psping -s 192.168.0.100:5000

### On the second machine:

psping -b first_machine_ip:first_machine_defined_port

Example: psping -b 192.168.0.100:5000

Answer (score -4):

You can right-click on the LAN connection and then Check the 'Status'. That will give you the link speed. You can also open a command prompt and run ping.exe to ping other computers on the network.

Comment: Link speed doesn't reflect the actual speed of the network.  Ping and tracert in Windows commandline would probably do what you're looking for...

Comment: Link speed is irrelevant.  And 32 byte packets simply will not tell me anything (will always be < 1ms).  Trace route will also not work because there are no hops.  Thanks though.

Comment: Or just copy a large file over the network and just do the math. It will give you the network throughput. 

You could also monitor this with 'Networking' Tab in the task manager. Be sure to add the additional columns.